# Can anyone explain how to integrate Google Analytics on iOS by swift without cocoapods?

Tags: swift, google-analytics

I've read Google's only swift [guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift) for analytics and I got some errors. When I researched them people said Cocoapods method have some bugs. And how to integrate Google Analytics on iOS by swift without cocoapods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if Google Analytics for iOS will be able to provide you with all the needed analytics for a mobile app, but if you have decided this is the way to go then here is something that may help.

Below if a guide to setting up the Google Analytics SDK in iOS manually, it is a tutorial on the Ray Wenderlich site (which is always a great resource). It is for iOS 7 but should point you down the right path...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios